# Dropdown menu not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have navigation which created with Bootstrap. Its working fine in PC and tablet. But in mobile its load the dropdown it self.

**Current mobile view**

[Current mobile view  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0fWL.jpg)

**I need as like** normal view. (Check comment I cant add more than 2 links)

Code is added on  https://jsfiddle.net/sqzbqh4h/2/

```
<section id="header">
    <header class="">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="top-line bottom_header">
                <div class="clear_fix">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.php">
                                <img src="./assets/images/logo2.png" class="img-logo">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: right"></div>
                    <div class="row col-sm-8 no-pad-left">
                        <div class="top-info">
                            <div class="social-top">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-sub">
                                    <li><a href="">branch network</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">downloads</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">corporate info</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">careers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">csr</a></li>
                                    <li><a style="color: #f58220 !important;" href="">Login</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="ul-language">
                                    <li class="dropdown hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            English <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Sinhala</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 no-pad-right-md bottom-info">
                            <div class="right-info" style=" margin-top: 8px;">
                                <div class="col-sm-4 middle-nav-item no-pad-both">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 no-pad-both">
                                        <div class="col-sm-1 middle-nav-icon middle-nav-icon-first ">
                                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 no-pad-right no-pad-right-md">
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="middle-nav-header">Company Insurance Limited</span>
                                                <br>
                                                <span class="middle-nav-text" >  Brisbain</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4 middle-nav-item no-pad-both">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 no-pad-both">
                                        <div class="col-sm-1 middle-nav-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 no-pad-right-md">
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="middle-nav-header">Mon - Sat 9:00 - 18:00</span>
                                                <br>
                                                <span class="middle-nav-text">Sunday CLOSED</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3 middle-nav-item no-pad-both">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 no-pad-both">
                                        <div class="col-sm-1 middle-nav-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 no-pad-right-md">
                                            <p>
                                                <span class="middle-nav-header">011 257 4721</span>
                                                <br>
                                                <span class="middle-nav-text">Free Call</span>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mainmenu-area">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 collapse navbar-collapse nav-div" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-main">
                        <li>
                            <a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown main-dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                About
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu main-dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Our Company</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Mission</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Our Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Gallery</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Mobile need like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/7BiOe.jpg

Comment: any answers please ??